# Most efficient way to sort and access final values

Tags: java

I have a class called "ClientFontRenderer" and I want to know the best way to store this. The method is being called every frame update which can be extremely quick so I'm not sure if I'm able to use arrays. What is the best way to store these variables in such a way that I can load them without a problem?

```
public class FontManager {
public static final FontManager INSTANCE;

private ClientFontRenderer LATOREGULAR, LATOSMALL, LATOBOLD;

private ClientFontRenderer SANSREGULAR, SANSBOLD, SANSITALIC;

public FontManager() {

}

public void initialize() {
    LATOREGULAR = new ClientFontRenderer("Lato-Light", 16.0F);
    LATOSMALL = new ClientFontRenderer("Lato-Light", 11.0F);
    LATOBOLD = new ClientFontRenderer("Lato-Bold", 16.0F);
    SANSREGULAR = new ClientFontRenderer("Sans-Regular", 16.0F);
}

public ClientFontRenderer loadFont(FontType type) {
    switch(type) {
        case LATO_REGULAR:
            return LATOREGULAR;
        case LATO_SMALL:
            return LATOSMALL;
        case LATO_BOLD:
            return LATOBOLD;
        case SANS_REGULAR:
            return SANSREGULAR;
        case SANS_BOLD:
            return SANSBOLD;
        case SANS_ITALIC:
            return SANSITALIC;
        default:
            return LATOREGULAR;
    }
}

static {
    INSTANCE = new FontManager();
}

public enum FontType {
    LATO_REGULAR,
    LATO_SMALL,
    LATO_BOLD,
    SANS_REGULAR,
    SANS_BOLD,
    SANS_ITALIC
}
```

Comment: which of the values are supposed to be `final` as the question mentions? Just because you use upper-case names doesn't make it final. If you're worried about array performance, maybe an `EnumMap<FontType, ClientFontRenderer>` is more applicable? Also, I don't think you need to have an instance of the FontManager inside an instance of FontManager.
I also think that you can move the whole initialize block into the constructor imo.

Comment: Loading fonts _every frame_ seems very resource intensive. You should only reload fonts (and rerender any text) upon a user font change

Comment: The next frame renders over the previous one so It has to be rendered every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imo since you only used static initializers, you can make `loadFont` static as well

```
public class FontManager {

  private static final EnumMap<FontType, ClientFontRenderer> fontMap = new EnumMap<>(FontType.class);

  static {
      fontMap.put(FontType.LATO_REGULAR, new ClientFontRenderer("Lato-Light", 16.0F);
      ...
  }

  public static ClientFontRenderer loadFont(FontType type) {
      return fontMap.get(type);
  }

  public enum FontType {
      LATO_REGULAR,
      LATO_SMALL,
      LATO_BOLD,
      SANS_REGULAR,
      SANS_BOLD,
      SANS_ITALIC
  }
)
```